# Why is the OpenLDAP for windows installer asking for a Serial Number?

Tags: openldap, sourceforge

I downloaded OpenLDAP for Windows (2.4.43 x86) from SourceForge and the installer is asking for a Serial Number:

[image: OpenLDAP For Windows Installer]

As far as I can find there is no such thing?

I tried entering anything but the next button will not allow me to progress

Comment: They should call them closed ldap.

Comment: There's an option of installing it from here: http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it helps you further, but I found you can install the [Version 2.4.32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openldapwindows/files/openldap-2.4.32) without registration. The feature you need might be however not supported by this old version.

Answer (score 4):

This question is very old, but in case anyone else gets to this page, the answer is quite simple. Read the instructions :-)

1. Enter an organisation name
2. Take a screen shot
3. Email it to the address specified (currently info@matear.eu - but use the address that it tells you)

Clicking the "back" button on the OP's dialogue would reveal what needs to be done:

[image: Open LDAP Instructions]

Comment: Follow-up: I did email them at the time, and never got a reply.

I ended up using a different OpenLDAP solution (which was actually "open" :D)

Comment: Also, those instructions don't say anything about a registration code.

Comment: You are not answering "Why".

Comment: No, I was answering the subquestion "As far as I can find there is no such thing?" The "why" is detailed in the bottom paragraph of the screenshot :-)